# How to use sed to add a new line of text after matched pattern?

Tags: regex, sed, octopress

I'm trying to add one more line to my posts in Octopress. It's

`comments: true`

I have about 200 posts so I would like to do it in one go. I was testing with this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
echo title: 'Blah Blah.' | sed "s/'title: .*'/'title: .*'\n'comments: true'\n/g"
```

The result I want is.

```
title: 'Blah Blah.'
comments: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
echo title: 'Blah Blah.' | sed "s/'title: .*'/'\1\r\ncomments: true'\n/g"
```

@BigOldTree 's suggestion:

```
echo title: 'Blah Blah.' | sed "/title: .*/a comments: true"
```

Comment: why don't you use a which is sed way to do it instead of using substitution, which works but requires more typing?

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue! (as an alternative to sed, which might be better suited for this task)

print on the next line after pattern

```
$ awk '1; /pattern/{print "comments: true"}' file
```

print on the previous line of pattern

```
$ awk '/pattern/{print "comments: true"} 1' file
```

print on the same line of pattern

```
$ awk '/pattern/{print $0, "comments: true"; next} 1'
```